# Передача list в метод Datatable c#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview, datatable

Вот есть загрузка формы

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Players player1 = new Players("Team", "Trainer", "Country", "Name", "Surname");
      dataGridView1.DataSource = player1.DisplayInfo();
}
```

В файле класса Players есть метод DisplayInfo

```
 public new DataTable DisplayInfo()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Team Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Trainer", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Player Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Player Surname", typeof(string));
            table.Rows.Add(TeamName, TeamTrainer, TeamCountry, PlayerName, PlayerSurname);
            
            return table;
        }
```

Как мне в метод DisplayInfo передать вот такой list. Где-то запутался и не могу найти толком никакой информации

```
 List<Players> players = new List<Players>()
             { new Players("Team", "Trainer", "Country", "Name", "Surname"),
                new Players("Team", "Trainer", "Country", "Name", "Surname"),
                new Players("Team", "Trainer", "Country", "Name", "Surname"),
                new Players("Team", "Trainer", "Country", "Name", "Surname") };
```

Вот я изменил и не работает

```
 List<Players> players = new List<Players>();
            players.Add(new Players("Team", "Trainer", "Country", "Name", "Surname"));
            players.Add(new Players("Team2", "Trainer2", "Country2", "Name2", "Surname2"));
            players.Add(new Players("Team3", "Trainer3", "Country3", "Name3", "Surname3"));
            players.Add(new Players("Team4", "Trainer4", "Country4", "Name4", "Surname4"));
            dataGridView1.DataSource = players.DisplayInfo(players);
```

```
public new DataTable DisplayInfo(List<Players> n)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Team Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Trainer", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Player Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Player Surname", typeof(string));
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(TeamName[i], TeamTrainer[i], TeamCountry[i], PlayerName[i], PlayerSurname[i]);
            }
            
            
            return table;
        }
```

Выдает ошибку List  не содержит определения DisplayInfo

Comment: Вы в скобочках у метода аргументы умеете добавлять?

Comment: `table.Rows.Add(n[i].TeamName, ...);` Вынесите метод DisplayInfo из класса Player, его там не должно быть. По обрезкам кода ничего не понятно, почему оно у вас оно именно так сделано, так же вы оставили в секрете, какую задачу вы решаете. Играть в Вангу не буду. `Players` - это что за "игроки", что содержит этот класс? Информацию об одном игроке? Тогда почему Players, а не Player? И почему метод у игрока DisplayInfo делает вот это вот все, что вы показали? Что он должен делать?